# Format String Numeric to Currency

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting

I need to read a number in the following format to 1000 and convert currency.
Note that number above "1000" realy would be 10.00.
Is there any method to convert this format?

Comment: You probably want to do a `/ 100` before using `string.Format` as Icarus suggests.

Comment: What language? C#, Java...? If C# then you would want to convert to decimal, divide by 100, then convert to string as Icarus suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
public String FormatValue( int valueAsCents ){
  Decimal.Divide( (decimal)valueAsCents , 100.0 ).ToString("C");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string.Format("{0:c}",your_value)
```

**UPDATE (thanks for the comments)**

```
string.Format("{0:c}",your_value/100);
```

Comment: Be sure to divide by 100 first.

Answer (score 1):

Icarus' answer will result in $1,000, the below is what you want.

```
string.Format("{0:c}",your_value/100)
```